# React functional component doesn't re-render when prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect

I'm using axios to request in my useEffect and the prop I pass is only a simple id. Here's the main part of my code;

```
    return (
        <>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
```

Comment: stationId should be passed as dependency of ```useEffect: }, [stationId]);```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to pass the prop `stationData` in the dependency array:

```
    const [stationData, setStationData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`Fetching station ${stationId}`)
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/stations/${stationId}`)
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                setStationData(response.data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, [stationData]); <--- HERE

    return (
        <>
            <Table striped bordered hover>
```

Comment: It works, but I get an infinite number of requests, why is that?

Comment: useEffect is similar to componentDidMount, each time after the mounting phase, the function is called based on the dependency you have specified.

Comment: For your error, it might be that your state variable gets updated multiple times, which triggers the useEffect hook.